# How to find the pattern of occurrences of events/letters/?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, tidyverse

I have a data set of events (letters in this case) and I would like to find out which letters triggered the occurrence of which letters (for example, that always letter `c` is first then `d` then `i`). In other words, to check if there is a pattern and what is the pattern in the occurrence of those letters.

`set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(letters[1:6], 500, replace=TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example code you could try something like

```
freqtab <- table(df$x[-length(df$x)], df$x[-1])
```

which would give you in full (earlier letters are rows and following letters are columns)

```
freqtab

#     a  b  c  d  e  f
#  a 13 13 19 11 12 13
#  b 17 16 17 10 17 15
#  c 13 16 18 14 17 14
#  d  8 17 16  9  9 13
#  e 20 13 10 13 15 11
#  f 10 16 12 15 13 14
```

and if you wanted to get a particular row, such as the frequencies of letters following `c`, you could use

```
freqtab["c", ]
#  a  b  c  d  e  f 
# 13 16 18 14 17 14
```

There are many other ways to approach this

Comment: Thanks! `table()` is miraculous, I didn't know that I can discard the last and the first row to get the frequencies of the following letters per letter.